# In Safari latest versions some elements goes above the scroll bar

Tags: html, css, ios, sass, cross-browser

I want to make a banner that is full screen and fixed to top. But only on safar 16.3, it goes above the scroll bar as well.
[image: Screenshot taken from Browserstack]

its easy to recreate.

```
.anyelement {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Just want to prevent this and behave line a normal browser
[image: This is from chrome which is the default and expected behaviour]